# Convert Windows-1252 csv to UTF-8 using PHP

Tags: php, drupal

I'm using fopen to read in a csv and fgetcsv to read the csv lines. The csv is encoded as Windows-1252, how do I convert this to UTF-8 so it doesn't cut lines with none standard characters?

So far I've tried the following:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_GB.UTF-8');
```

and

```
drupal_convert_to_utf8($csv_line[3], 'Windows-1251'); // (I'm using Drupal 6.16)
```

Both seem to fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php) for this kind of work.

Comment: I've looked into iconv using the following:

$str = 'Felleskjøpet';
echo iconv('Windows-1252', 'UTF-8', $str);

This outputs:

Felleskj¿pet

Comment: Are you sure your input is in `Windows-1252` ? What makes you belive that ?

Comment: When I saved the test php the enc type was wrong setting it to Windows-1525 works.

My next issue is getting it to work with an array of data.

Comment: You have to be extremely careful using `iconv` because if there is a _single_ UTF-8 character in your CSV, it will turn into gibberish.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know the drupal_convert_to_utf8 function, but have a look at mb_convert_encoding.

Try using mb_list_encodings to be sure your implementation supports Windows-1252. If not try using ISO 8859-1, it is basicly the same ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252 ).

You should also make sure your csv actually is in Windows-1252. Try using mb_detect_encoding for this and make use of the strict flag.